# phpMyAdmin and mysqli_sql_exception error

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, whm

I can only access phpMyadmin through WHM when I have the following in my `/etc/my.cnf` file -

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

But then I am not able to retrieve the data from mysql table in my webpages.

However when I remove `skip-grant-tables` from `my.cnf`, I an able to view the data in my webpages but phpMyAdmin stops working. I get the message -

> mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES)

I am using `AlmaLinux 8`.